# display hashmapped values in alertbox in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-adapter, android-checkbox

I am getting some details from webservice and i need to display those details with  checkboxes associated with it on its leftside dynamically(using java code).I already mapped all details to a Hashmap Arraylist correctly,What to do next is that display all the details to the alertbox,which is defined in my code..I tried a lot.Can anybody help me any help will be highly appreciable.....

```
selectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                            private Builder mDialog;

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)  {

                                Log.e(tag,"alertbox for onclickworked");
                                Context c =getParent();
                                this.mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                                alertDialog = mDialog.create();
                                // Setting Dialog Title
                                 alertDialog.setTitle("Intrested In");


                                 new Serviceclass().execute();




                        // Setting Icon to Dialog
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.gate_logo);


                        alertDialog.show();

                            }
                            class Serviceclass extends AsyncTask<Void,  Void, String>
                             {

                                 protected String doInBackground(
                                            Void... params) {
                             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e(tag,"inside getvaluesforcheckbox()");
                                 offferList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                                 Log.e(tag,"arraylist created");
                                 try{
                                UserFunctions usf=new UserFunctions();

                                JSONObject json2 = usf.intrestlist(user_id);

                                Log.e(tag,"before try");

                                    Log.e(tag,"after try");
                                JSONArray contacts = json2.getJSONArray("interested_list");

                                Log.e(tag,"outside forloop");
                                for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
                                    Log.e(tag,"inside forloop");
                                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                                    map.put(KEY_INTRESTID, c.getString("interested_id"));
                                    Log.e("requestclass.java",c.getString("interested_id"));
                                    map.put(KEY_INTRESTNAME, c.getString("interested_name"));
                                    Log.e("requestclass.java",c.getString("interested_name"));
                                    map.put(KEY_STAUS, c.getString("status"));
                                    Log.e("requestclass.java",c.getString("status"));
                                    if(c.getString("interested_info").equals("null"))
                                    {
                                         map.put(KEY_INTERESTINFO,"");  
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    map.put(KEY_INTERESTINFO,c.getString("interested_info"));
                                    }
                                    offferList.add(map);
//                                  cadapter = new ClientListAdapter(this, R.layout.client_list,
//                                          ClientDetailsCollection.getClientDetailssAsArray(), this);


                                }
                                Log.e(tag,"datas added to arraylist");
                                checkboxgeneration();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                return null;





                            }
                                 protected void onPostExecute() {
HERE I NEED TO WRITE THE CODE
                                     }

                             }
```

Advance Thanks.....

Answer (score 0):

You have web request to make and display the records in dialog. Here what I suggest you.
1. Use [DialogFragments.](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)
2. Inside fragment make a listview, create custom adapter according to your design.
 3. Make Web Request inside fragment. 
4. For your ease you can read this Tutorial [Android DialogFragment and ListView](http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/android-dialogfragment-listview.html)